# Alert view with JSON data

Tags: ios, json, swift, alert

I have a JSON data which is getting from the response. I want to show the data into an alert view.

1.this is my message:

```
"error": {
        "email": [
            "The email has already been taken."
        ],
        "phone": [
            "The phone has already been taken."
        ]
    }
```

2. my Swift code:

   ```
   let errormessage = jsonObj.value(forkey: "error")
   createAlert(title: "Try again" , message: errormessage as! String)
   ```

Someone please help me how to display the errormessage in an alert it would be very much helpful

Comment: You need to decide if you want to show the error message for phone or email

Comment: What is the type of `jsonObj` ?

Comment: I have to show both in alert dialog @ joakim

Comment: its object inside obj @rajesh

Comment: *object* is not a type in terms of Swift.

Comment: This is not valid approach for error handling, your API should return error message only with specific scenario.

Comment: @NikunjKumbhani  then tell me how to show NSDictionary in alert as NSDictionary cannot be converted to a string. please help me

Comment: Learn to **read** JSON. It's pretty easy. There are only two collection types `[]` is array (index subscripted), `{}` is dictionary (key subscripted).

Comment: for now, I have used createAlert(title: "Try again", message: "email or phone already exits".). if anyone finds any solution do send me sample code, please. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `NSDictionary` in swift. Use `[String:Any]`. Get all values of the dictionary and join the array of strings. And join the error with a new line as a separator.

```
let jsonObj:[String: Any] = ["error": [
                "email": ["The email has already been taken."],
                "phone": ["The phone has already been taken."]]
                ]
if let errorMsgs = jsonObj["error"] as? [String: [String]] {
    let errMsg = errorMsgs.values.map { $0.reduce("", +) }.joined(separator: "\n")
    print(errMsg)
    createAlert(title: "Try again" , message: errMsg)
}
```

[image]

Comment: this helped me much. Thank you <3

Comment: I have accepted it

Answer (score 0):

You can parse your json like this:

```
func jsonSerializer() {
    let jsonString = """
{
    "error": {
        "email": [
        "The email has already been taken."
        ],
        "phone": [
        "The phone has already been taken."
        ]
    }
}
"""
    let data = Data(jsonString.utf8)

    do {
        if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String: Any] {
            if let error = json["error"] as? [String: Any] {
                if let email = error["email"] as? [String],  email.count > 0 {
                    print(email[0])
//                    createAlert(title: "Try again", message: email[0])
                }
                if let phone = error["phone"] as? [String],  phone.count > 0 {
                    print(phone[0])
//                    createAlert(title: "Try again", message: phone[0])
                }
            }
        }
    } catch let parseError {
        print("parsing error: \(parseError)")
        let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        print("raw response: \(responseString!)")
    }
}
```